php CodeIgnitor dynamic content passing to Views
I am working on a model to generate responses for the selected AImodels and send them to views at the end simultaneously as you can see in my process method below.
<?php

namespace App\Controllers;

use App\Models\ExamModel;
use App\Models\VendorModel;
use App\Models\ExamTopicModel;
use App\Models\CertificationModel;
use App\Models\AIResponseModel;
use React\Promise\Promise;

class OptionController extends BaseController
{
    public function index()
    {
        // Display the form view
        return view('options_form');
    }
public function process()
{
    $db = \Config\Database::connect();

    $examModel = new ExamModel();
    $examTopicModel = new ExamTopicModel();
    $certificationModel = new CertificationModel();
    $vendorModel = new VendorModel();
    $responseModel = new AIResponseModel();

    // Get form inputs
    $exam_codes_raw = $this->request->getPost('examCodes'); // The raw input string of exam codes
    $aiModels = $this->request->getPost('aiModel'); // Array of selected AI models
    $prompt_template = $this->request->getPost('prompt'); // User-provided prompt
    $project_name = $this->request->getPost('projectName'); // User-provided project name

    // Ensure $exam_codes_raw is treated as a string
    if (is_array($exam_codes_raw)) {
        $exam_codes_raw = implode("\n", $exam_codes_raw); // Convert array to string
    }

    // Split the raw exam codes string into an array
    $exam_codes = preg_split('/[\r\n,]+/', trim($exam_codes_raw));

    $responses = [];
    $insertedId = null; // Initialize variable to avoid "undefined variable" errors

    // Determine if headings should be applied based on keywords in the prompt template
    $keywords = ['information', 'info', 'article', 'articles', 'post', 'something', 'tell', 'tell me', 'artical', 'arrticle', 'poost', 'say', 'illuminate', 'shed'];
    $applyHeadings = false;
    foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
        if (stripos($prompt_template, $keyword) !== false) {
            $applyHeadings = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Loop through each exam code
    foreach ($exam_codes as $exam_code) {
        // Trim any extra whitespace for each exam code
        $exam_code = trim($exam_code);

        // Fetch exam details from the database
        $exam = $examModel->where('exam_code', $exam_code)->first();
        if ($exam === null) {    
            $responses[$exam_code] = [
                'error' => 'Could not find data for exam code ' . $exam_code,
                'model' => []
            ];
            continue;
        }

        $certification = $certificationModel->find($exam['certification_ids']);
        if ($certification === null) {
            $responses[$exam_code] = [
                'error' => 'Could not find certification data for exam code ' . $exam_code,
                'model' => []
            ];
            continue;
        }

        $vendor = $vendorModel->find($exam['vendor_id']);
        if ($vendor === null) {
            $responses[$exam_code] = [
                'error' => 'Could not find vendor data for exam code ' . $exam_code,
                'model' => []
            ];
            continue;
        }

        $topics = $examTopicModel->where('exam_code', $exam_code)->findAll();
        $topicsSections = array_map(function($topic) {
            return $topic['description'];
        }, $topics);

        // Process the prompt
        $parsed_prompt = $this->processPrompt(
            $exam_code,
            $prompt_template,
            $exam['name'],
            $exam['exam_shortname'],
            $certification['detail_name'],
            $certification['cert_shortname'],
            $vendor['name'],
            $topicsSections // Pass the array of topics
        );

        // Check if there was an error in processing the prompt
        if (strpos($parsed_prompt, 'Error:') !== false) {
            // Handle the error by skipping the AI generation for this exam code
            $responses[$exam_code] = [
                'error' => $parsed_prompt,
                'model' => []
            ];
        }

        // Call the respective AI models for the parsed prompt
        foreach ($aiModels as $aiModel) {
            $response = '';
            $modelName = ucfirst($aiModel); // Example: 'openai' becomes 'OpenAI'
            try {
                switch ($aiModel) {
                    // Handle AI model requests as needed
                    case 'openai-gpt-3.5-Turbo':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->generateTextOpenAI($parsed_prompt, $apiKey);
                        break;
                    case 'cohere':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->generateTextCohere($parsed_prompt, $apiKey, $exam_code);
                        break;
                    case 'claude-3-Opus':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->generateTextClaudeOpus($parsed_prompt, $apiKey);
                        break;
                    case 'openai-gpt-4o-mini':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->generateTextOpenAIGPT4omini($parsed_prompt, $apiKey);
                        break;
                    case 'claude-3-Haiku':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->(generateTextClaudeHaiku$parsed_prompt, $apiKey);
                        break;
                    case 'claude-3.5-Sonnet':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->generateTextClaudeSonnet($parsed_prompt, $apiKey);
                        break;
                    case 'openai-gpt-4-turbo':
                        $apiKey = '';
                        $response = $this->generateTextOpenAIGPT4turbo($parsed_prompt, $apiKey);
                        break;
                }

                $responses[$exam_code]['model'][$aiModel] = $response;

                // Store the AI model name and its response
                $responseDatetime = date('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // Current date and time

                // Insert data into the table
                $builder = $db->table('responses');

                // Prepare the data to insert
                $data = [
                    'ai_model' => $modelName,
                    'created_at' => $responseDatetime,
                    'prompt' => $parsed_prompt, // Store the actual parsed prompt
                    'response' => $response, // Store the AI generated response
                    'project_name' => $project_name, // Store the project name
                ];
                $builder->insert($data);
                $insertedId = $db->insertID();

            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                // Display error message if something goes wrong
                $responses[$exam_code]['model'][$modelName] = "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
            }
        }
    }

    return view('response_view', [
        'insertedId' => $insertedId,
        'responses' => $responses
    ]);
}

The response is being sent to the views as whole. I have to wait for all my responses to be completed then appear on the views all at once.
**

The problem is I want the dynamic responses on my views. The moment an
AiModel that was selected is done with generation it should appear on
the views instead of waiting for all of them.

**
Below is my views code:
    <body>
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar  -->
        <nav id="sidebar">
            <div class="sidebar-header">
                <h3>AI Prompt Model</h3>
            </div>
            <ul class="list-unstyled components">
                <li class="active">
                    <ul class="collapse list-unstyled" id="homeSubmenu">
                        <li>
                            <a onclick="window.location.href='<?= base_url('dashboard'); ?>'">Go to Dashboard</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a onclick="window.location.href='<?= base_url('homepage'); ?>'">Go to Home Page</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </nav>
    <div class="main-content">
        <h1>AI Model Responses</h1>
        <div class="exam-section">
            <button id="compareButton">Compare Selected</button>
            <table>
                <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Select</th>
                    <th>Exam Code</th>
                    <th>AI Model</th>
                    <th>Response</th>
                    <th>Action</th> <!-- Add this column -->
                </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php
                $exam_responses = [];

                foreach ($responses as $exam_code => $data):
                    if (isset($data['model']) && !empty($data['model'])):
                        foreach ($data['model'] as $model => $response):
                            $normalized_model = strtolower($model);

                            if (!isset($exam_responses[$exam_code])) {
                                $exam_responses[$exam_code] = [];
                            }

                            // Ensure the response is a string
                            if (is_array($response)) {
                                // If response is an array, assume it's the first item in the array
                                $response = isset($response['response']) ? $response['response'] : '';
                            }

                            $response = preg_replace('/\*\*(.+?)\*\*/', '<strong>$1</strong>', $response);
                            $response = preg_replace('/^#### (.+)$/m', '<h4>$1</h4>', $response);
                            $response = preg_replace('/^### (.+)$/m', '<h3>$1</h3>', $response);
                            $response = preg_replace('/^## (.+)$/m', '<h2>$1</h2>', $response);
                            if (!isset($exam_responses[$exam_code][$normalized_model])) {
                                $exam_responses[$exam_code][$normalized_model] = $response;
                            }
                        endforeach;
                    endif;
                endforeach;
                ?>

                <?php foreach ($exam_responses as $exam_code => $models):
                    foreach ($models as $model => $response):
                        $decoded_response = is_string($response) ? htmlspecialchars_decode($response) : '';
                        ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="response-checkbox"
                                       data-exam-code="<?= htmlspecialchars($exam_code) ?>"
                                       data-response="<?= htmlspecialchars($decoded_response) ?>"
                                       data-model="<?= htmlspecialchars(ucwords($model)) ?>">
                            </td>
                            <td><?= htmlspecialchars($exam_code) ?></td>
                            <td><?= htmlspecialchars(ucwords($model)) ?></td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="response-btn" onclick="toggleResponse(this)">View Response</button>
                                <div class="response-box"><?= htmlspecialchars_decode($decoded_response) ?></div>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <button class="delete-btn" data-id="<?= htmlspecialchars($insertedId) ?>"
                                        onclick="deleteRow(this)">Delete
                                </button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                endforeach;
                ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <a href="<?= base_url('optioncontroller'); ?>">Go back</a>
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Copy Notification -->
<div class="copy-notification" id="copyNotification">Response copied to clipboard</div>

<!-- Compare Modal -->
<div id="compareModal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <h2>Compare Responses</h2>
        <div id="compareResults"></div>
    </div>
</div>

Any help would be appreciated!

So you want them to be dynamically added ? Each time one of them is ready, it shows up ?

I have removed your API keys from the question. You should now replace those keys urgently. Please don't post keys in future code otherwise they may well get abused!!

    public function process()
{
    try {
        // Get the form inputs
        $exam_codes_raw = $this->request->getPost('examCodes');
        $aiModels = $this->request->getPost('aiModel');
        $prompt_template = $this->request->getPost('prompt');
        $project_name = $this->request->getPost('projectName');

        // Convert exam codes into an array
        if (is_array($exam_codes_raw)) {
            $exam_codes_raw = implode("\n", $exam_codes_raw); 
        }
        $exam_codes = preg_split('/[\r\n,]+/', trim($exam_codes_raw));

        // Initialize an array to store results
        $results = [];

        // Process each exam code and fetch AI model responses
        foreach ($exam_codes as $exam_code) {
            // Fetch exam data
            $exam = $this->fetchExamData($exam_code);
            if ($exam === null) {
                // If exam data is missing, store an error
                $results[] = [
                    'success' => false,
                    'error' => "Error: Could not find data for exam code $exam_code",
                    'examCode' => $exam_code,
                    'projectName' => $project_name // Include project name
                ];
                continue;
            }

            // Process the prompt for each AI model
        $parsed_prompt = $this->processPrompt(
            $exam_code,
            $prompt_template,
            $exam['name'],
            $exam['exam_shortname'],
            $exam['certification_detail_name'],
            $exam['certification_shortname'],
            $exam['vendor_name'],
            $exam['topics'],
            $exam['EXAM_DESCRIPTION'],
            $exam['EXAM_TOPIC'] // Pass the selected topic directly from the exam array
        );
            foreach ($aiModels as $aiModel) {
                try {
                    // Generate AI response
                    $response = $this->generateAIResponse($aiModel, $parsed_prompt);
                    
                    // Save the response to the database
                    $dataToSave = [
                        'ai_model' => $aiModel,
                        'prompt' => $parsed_prompt,
                        'response' => $response,
                        'created_at' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s'), // Set created_at to current timestamp
                        'project_name' => $project_name
                    ];
                    $this->saveResponse($dataToSave); // Call the save function

                    $results[] = [
                        'success' => true,
                        'aiModel' => $aiModel,
                        'response' => $response,
                        'examCode' => $exam_code,      // Include exam code
                        'projectName' => $project_name,  // Include project name
                        'prompt' => $parsed_prompt
                    ];
                } catch (\Exception $e) {
                    // Handle AI response errors
                    $results[] = [
                        'success' => false,
                        'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                        'aiModel' => $aiModel,
                        'examCode' => $exam_code,      // Include exam code
                        'projectName' => $project_name,  // Include project name
                        'prompt' => $parsed_prompt
                    ];
                }
            }
        }

        // Return the responses as JSON
        $this->response->setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        echo json_encode(['responses' => $results]);
        exit;
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        error_log('Processing error: ' . $e->getMessage());
        $this->response->setStatusCode(500);
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'Internal Server Error']);
        exit;
    }
}

<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.getElementById('optionsForm').addEventListener('submit', async function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(event.target);
    
        pendingResponses = formData.getAll('aiModel[]').length;
        updateLoader();
    
        for (let model of formData.getAll('aiModel[]')) {
            let newFormData = new FormData();
            newFormData.append('prompt', formData.get('prompt'));
            newFormData.append('projectName', formData.get('projectName'));
    
            for (let examCode of formData.getAll('examCodes[]')) {
                newFormData.append('examCodes[]', examCode);
            }
    
            newFormData.append('aiModel[]', model);
    
            fetchResponse(newFormData).then((response) => {
                addResponseBox(model, formData.get('prompt'), response, formData.getAll('examCodes[]'), formData.get('projectName'));
            }).catch(error => {
                console.error('Error fetching response:', error);
                addResponseBox(model, formData.get('prompt'), { response: 'Error fetching response', responseID: null }, formData.getAll('examCodes[]'), formData.get('projectName'));
            }).finally(() => {
                pendingResponses--; 
                updateLoader(); 
            });
        }
    });
    
    async function fetchResponse(formData) {
        try {
            const response = await fetch('process', {
                method: 'POST',
                body: formData
            });
    
            if (!response.ok) {
                console.error('Network response was not ok', response.statusText);
                alert('Network error: ' + response.statusText);
                throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
            }
    
            const data = await response.json();
            console.log('Server response:', data);
    
            if (data.status === 'error') {
                alert(`Error: ${data.message}`);
                throw new Error(data.message);
            }
    
            return data.responses ? data.responses[0] : { response: 'No response available', responseID: null };
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching response:', error);
            alert('An error occurred: ' + error.message);
            throw error;
        }
    }
function addResponseBox(aiModel, prompt, responseData, examCodes, projectName) {
        let responseBox = document.createElement('div');
        responseBox.className = 'response-box';

        let examCodesDiv = document.createElement('div');
        examCodesDiv.innerHTML = examCodes.join(", ");
        responseBox.appendChild(examCodesDiv);

        let modelDiv = document.createElement('div');
        modelDiv.innerHTML = aiModel;
        responseBox.appendChild(modelDiv);

        let projectDiv = document.createElement('div');
        projectDiv.innerHTML = projectName;
        responseBox.appendChild(projectDiv);

        let promptDiv = document.createElement('div');
        promptDiv.className = 'prompt-box';
        promptDiv.innerHTML = responseData.prompt;
        responseBox.appendChild(promptDiv);

        let responseDiv = document.createElement('div');
        responseDiv.className = 'response-content';
        
        // Log input and output for debugging
        console.log('Input to markdown function:', responseData.response);
        responseDiv.innerHTML = markdownToHtmlWithEncoding(responseData.response);
        console.log('Output from markdown function:', responseDiv.innerHTML);
        
        responseBox.appendChild(responseDiv);

        let deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
        deleteButton.innerHTML = 'Delete';
        deleteButton.className = 'delete-button'; 
        deleteButton.style.minWidth = "50px"; 
        deleteButton.style.marginLeft = "10px"; 

        deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
            responseBox.remove(); 
        });

        let actionDiv = document.createElement('div');
        actionDiv.className = 'action-column'; 
        actionDiv.appendChild(deleteButton);

        responseBox.appendChild(examCodesDiv);
        responseBox.appendChild(modelDiv);
        responseBox.appendChild(projectDiv);
        responseBox.appendChild(promptDiv);
        responseBox.appendChild(actionDiv);
        responseBox.appendChild(responseDiv);

 // Insert the response box after the heading row
    responseTableBody.insertBefore(responseBox, responseTableBody.children[1]);

        promptDiv.addEventListener('click', function () {
            responseDiv.style.display = responseDiv.style.display === "none" ? "block" : "none";
        });
    }
    </script>

This AJAX code worked for me! It is sending the request to process method and the moment an Ai model is done with the response, it is sent to the frontend immediately.
